# Sum of values in a cycle java

Tags: java, arrays

So i have an array and the cycle outputs the amount of rows that contain 3 or more values of 1

```java
int i, j,rcount,threecount;
double A[][] = {{0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5},
                {0, 1, 0, 1, 1},
                {0.5,1,0.5,0.5,0},
                {0,0.5,0,0.5,0},
                {1,1,1,1,1},
                {0,0,0,0.5,0.5},
                {0,0.5,0,0,1}};
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
          threeCount = 0;
          rcount = 0;
          for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
              if (A[i][j] == 1) threeCount++;
          }
          if (threeCount >= 3 )
              rcount++;
          if (rcount==1)
              System.out.print((rcount ) + " ");
}
```

Right now the output is

```
0 1 0 0 1 0 0
```

I want the the output to be

```
2
```

Comment: Seems like you basically have the idea--I think you can do this. Whenever `threeCount >= 3`, you tick up `rcount`. Move `rcount = 0` and the `println` outside the loop (before the loop and after the loop respectively) and you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i ++) {
    int rowCount = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < A[i].length; j++) {
        if (A[i][j] == 1) {
            rowCount++;
        }
    }
    if (rowCount > 2) {
        count++;
    }
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use streams.

```
  double A[][] = { { 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5
        }, { 0, 1, 0, 1, 1
        }, { 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0
        }, { 0, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0
        }, { 1, 1, 1, 1, 0
        }, { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
        }, { 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5
        }, { 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 1
        }
  };

  long count = Arrays.stream(A).mapToLong(
        arr -> Arrays.stream(arr).filter(value -> value == 1).count()).filter(
              onesCount -> onesCount >= 3).count();

  System.out.println(count);
```

Here is how it works:

Your array A is an array of arrays.

1. `Arrays.stream()` creates a `stream` of the contents of the array.  In your case it would be the arrays of the numbers.
2. `arr->Arrays.stream(arr).filter(value->value==1).count()` does the same thing but this time the stream is the actual numbers themselves.  They are then passed thru a filter, passing only 1's and counting them.
   Because `count()` returns a long value, all of this needs to be put in a `mapToLong` resulting in this: `mapToLong(arr -> Arrays.stream(arr).filter(value -> value == 1).count())`.
3. The output of that, which are counts of 1's in each array is now filtered once again and counted via `filter(onesCount -> onesCount >= 3).count()` looking for counts `>= 3`.  Those are then returned as the final `long`result.

Comment: This would be the way to go normally, but I guess the selected answer is more beginner-friendly.

Comment: The answer was selected a a while ago before my post.  I was just showing an alternative that might prove useful to someone.

Comment: I don't agree really  with P. Soutzikevich. Streams are great but you don't have to use them whenever possible imo. In this case it does not make sense to me, to convert both arrays to a stream first just to save two lines of code :) But I guess it's a matter of taste. And as @WJS said he showed another way to do it.